# How to solve this RecurrenceTable in Mathematica

Tags: sequence

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q:  How to define this in Mathematica.

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[2 n] == a[n] + 1, a[2 n + 1] == a[n] + 3, a[1] == 1},a,{n,1,10}]
```

Comment: You should be getting an error which tells you what the problem is: _RecurrenceTable::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined._

Answer (score 2):

`RSolve` and `RecurrenceTable` can't seem to handle this.

You can at least get values from the sequence like this though:

```
sequence = Module[{a,n=1,seq = CreateDataStructure["LinkedList"]},
   seq["Append", 1];
   While[n < 100,
    a = seq["Part", n];
    seq["Append", a + 1];
    seq["Append", a + 3];
    ++n;]; Normal@seq
   ];

ListPlot[sequence, Filling -> Axis, AxesLabel -> {"n", "a[n]"}]
```

[image]